# import os, trying to refresh event variables after running a script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I install a program through python, *git* in this case.  Immediately after, I will call `os.system("git --version")` but the call doesn't go through because of the snapshot of variables has not been updated.

Is there a way to refresh the cmd prompt?  Maybe just reimport `os` or something?

The issue i am having is that after installing an application, the app related cmd commands are not yet key words.

I have noticed this is a reoccurring issue in all of my platform configuration installs.

I spent awhile reading docs but i havent see anything really jumping out at me other than the concept that *the env is pulls at the time of importing os* so maybe that means i could dump and reimport it.

Comment: You question is unclear. Please add some code (preferably an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Which OS are you running this script on?

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak was running it on windows.  I dont think we will be running it on mac anytime soon

Comment: "I end up running a script that modifies the environment, but it is not properly reflected in follow on function calls because it isnt in the path" - that is not how environment variables work. Why would it matter whether it's on the path? And is your Python program launching a *separate* script to change the environment variables? That won't work; a process can't change its parent's environment variables.

Comment: The base concept was:   Script installed Git.   Immediately following, i used "git --version" and it would throw an error because it didnt understand what *git* was.  I figured i needed to find a way to refresh the instance of Python's terminal environment, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i know where it will be installed, you can set env, and then call sub processes.

The issue i was having is that a lot of these executables assign their own path variables which is what i wanted to do.  Since i cant relaunch a new console due to security issues, the best course of action would be to navigate to the new applications target bin folder or otherwise and then set the env or pass it into subprocesses by appending it with Env variables.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the `os.getenv` instead of the `os.environ`.
The getenv will get it from the actual os at the time you call it.

getenv: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getenv

-- Simple summary of the difference between those two:

`os.environ` - Loaded at import time (`import os`)

`os.getenv()` - Gets environment variable at time of call (with the C library function `getenv`)

Comment: I installed git.  Immediately after, i said something like: `os.system("git --version")` and it didnt seem to like it.  I am thinking that somehow the underlying terminal didnt understand the reference to git which was just installed.

Comment: Ah, what you want to do is execute a command with a command in the new path variable. Everything you execute inside of your python script will reflect on the env vars you got when starting the python executable, except if you would start a shell inside of your command. (Start bash with your command inside of it would maybe help).

Comment: yeah, thats what i was trying to convey.  Im trying to think if there is a way to reload the variables such that path and all variables will be updated.  could I reimport os and it would fetch the changed data?  It said in the descriptions on the site "It was stored at the point of import" so if i reimport it (if thats a thing) and voila.

Comment: Well, you can try to reload the os (and maybe the subprocess) module. Not sure if that works, I don't think so..

Comment: dratz.  Ever have that issue yourself, or is there a better way to resolve my target goal?

Comment: Try to start the `git` command with `subprocess.call` and `shell=True`. This might work, not sure. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Comment: im going to see if i can get that working and I will have to get back to you.  I think i have some simple test concepts i could use to test this concept.

Comment: Tom, When looking at the docs, it says that: *environ['HOME'] ....and is equivalent to getenv('HOME') in C* so i am inclined to believe it is not correct since those are obtained as a snapshot at application start.  I dont see it saying "At the time of the call" or any sort of update to accessed and updated path variables.  I will continue to look into this though

Comment: **Update**: your answer is wrong.   i tried to add to the path and then reference it and it didnt exist, so i was printing it all out.